# Laplace Transform initial value problem to solve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use the Laplace Transform to solve the initial value problem for $y''+3y'+2y=6e^{-t}$, $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=2$.

Comment: Start by taking the Laplace transform of both sides of the ODE. Is this homework?

Comment: What does the Laplace transform do to $y'$, to $y''$? What is the Laplace transform of the rhs?

Comment: What exactly is stopping you from solving the problem on your own?

Comment: @par yes this is homework. So I have L(y'')+3L(y')+2L(y)=6L(e^(-t)

Comment: @RonGordon, well we JUST learned about Laplace and I don't quite have the hang of it just yet. I know that i need to put the Laplace transform to each one, but from there, I get confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the LT of a derivative of $y$ is $s \hat{y}(s) - y(0)$.  This comes from integration by parts:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, y'(t) e^{-s t} = [y(t) e^{-s t}]_0^{\infty} + s \int_0^{\infty} dt \, y(t) e^{-s t}$$

Similarly, the LT of $y''$ is $s^2 \hat{y}(s) - s y(0) - y'(0)$.

The LT of the RHS is

$$6 \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{-(s+1) t} = \frac{6}{s+1}$$

Using the initial conditions specified, the differential equation is now an algebraic one:

$$(s^2+ 3 s + 2) \hat{y} - s-2 - 3 = \frac{6}{s+1}$$

Solving for $\hat{y}(s)$:

$$\hat{y}(s) = \frac{s+5}{(s+2)(s+1)} + \frac{6}{(s+2)(s+1)^2} = \frac{s^2+6 s+11}{(s+2)(s+1)^2}$$

There are a couple of ways to get $y(t)$ from $\hat{y}(s)$.  You may either use partial fractions or compute residues of $\hat{y}(s) e^{s t}$ at the poles $s=-2$ and $s=-1$.  I will illustrate the latter.

The pole $s=-2$ is simple so its residue is straightforward:

$$\text{Res}_{s=-2} \frac{s^2+6 s+11}{(s+2)(s+1)^2} e^{s t} = \frac{4-12+11}{(-2+1)^2} e^{-2 t} = 3 e^{-2 t} $$

The pole at $s=-1$, however, is a double pole and we use a derivative to compute the residue:

$$\begin{align}\text{Res}_{s=-1} \frac{s^2+6 s+11}{(s+2)(s+1)^2} e^{s t} &= \left [ \frac{d}{ds} \frac{(s^2+6 s+11) e^{s t}}{(s+2)}  \right ]_{s=-1}\\ &= \left [ \frac{e^{s t} \left(s^2+(s+2) (s (s+6)+11) t+4 s+1\right)}{(s+2)^2}\right ] _{s=-1}\\ &= (6 t-2 ) e^{-t}\end{align}$$

Therefore

$$y(t) = (6 t-2 ) e^{-t} + 3 e^{-2 t}$$

Comment: Wow thank you sooooo much! This has made things a little bit clear seeing it broken down.

Comment: @user1988: You're welcome - now you have two very nice derivations of the final result.  Amzoti did a good job showing you the partial fraction approach, which I suspect is the way you will be doing things.  I prefer the residue approach because, while it uses concepts that may be alien to first-timers, it is really not beyond the abilities of folks at this level and I am just too lazy to do partial fractions most of the time.  Anyway, good luck and I hope you learned something here.

Comment: I did! And we have actually learned both ways. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Ok, lets go slow.

- $\displaystyle \mathcal{L} (y'') = s^2 y(s) -s y(0) - y'(0)$
- $\displaystyle \mathcal{L} (y') = sy(s) - y(0)$
- $\displaystyle \mathcal{L} (y) = y(s)$

Now, we substitute all of those into the DEQ and arrive at:

$$s^2 y(s) -s -2 +3(y(s)-1) + 2y(s) = \frac{6}{s+1}$$

$$y(s) = \frac{s^2+6 s+11}{(s+1)^2(s+2)} =  \frac{3}{s+2}-\frac{2}{s+1}+\frac{6}{(s+1)^2}$$

Now, you can do the inverse of each term on the RHS.

$$y(t) = e^{-2 t} (e^t (6 t-2)+3)$$

Comment: I am lost, I am not quite sure if I can do it from there.

Comment: @user1988: I added updates to help guide you better. Are they clear?

Comment: Yes they are, thank you very much. So now would I plug in my initial values into the y(t)?

Comment: @user1988: If you look at the three right hand terms above, those already take your initial conditions into consideration (in the first hint we used them). All you do now is take the inverse Laplace of those three terms on the right and you are done. i suppose you know how to do that part. Ron Gordon provided a very nice approach to doing that, but not sure it will be clear to you at this point, but it is the best way. I did this the way I think you are likely learning it and are at. Regards

Comment: No,no I see it very clearly, you did a nice job as well. It was hard for me to see at first because I need to see it step by step. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @user1988: You are very welcome and if anything is confusing, just give a yell. Regards

Comment: I most definitely will!